# VBA, Updating link to other workbook in formula daily

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VBA programming and have an issue.

I have a base file called liquidity forecast in which I fill data from other documents in. The documents I collect data from is updated every day so the date in the name changes every day.

The Name goes "(Date, "YYMMDD") & "SE_Laizy.xlsx" so an example would be, 160229SE_Laizy.xlsx

When I collect data I use Index match formula. My problem is trying to update the link within the formula by using a date value.

Currently I write it like this,

```
ActiveCell.Range((Cells(1, 1)), (Cells(1, 1))).FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=INDEX('[" & Format(Date, "YYMMDD") &  "SE_Laizy.xlsx"]Visa'!R1:R1048576,MATCH(R2C,'[" & Format(Date, "YYMMDD") & "SE_Laizy.xlsx"]Visa'!C1,0),MATCH(""Ub perioden"",'[" & Format(Date, "YYMMDD") & "SE_Laizy.xlsx"]Visa'!R2,0))"
```

All I get from this is a NA. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please go back and edit the title of your question to reflect the content of your question.

Comment: Thanks, totally missed that!

Comment: `&  "SE_Laizy.xlsx"` should be `&  "SE_Laizy.xlsx...` etc. Your quotes are not placed right and not matched.

Comment: Thank you so much, working perfect now!

Answer (score 3):

I've added a parent worksheet reference and broken the [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) and 
[MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca)  functions into the three primary sections.

```
With Worksheets("Sheet2")
    .Cells(1, 1).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=INDEX('[" & Format(Date, "YYMMDD") & "SE_Laizy.xlsx]Visa'!C1:C16384, " & _
            "MATCH(R2C,'[" & Format(Date, "YYMMDD") & "SE_Laizy.xlsx]Visa'!C1, 0), " & _
            "MATCH(""Ub perioden"", '[" & Format(Date, "YYMMDD") & "SE_Laizy.xlsx]Visa'!R2, 0))"
End With
```

As noted, there were some misplaced quotes in the external workbook name. I'm not sure what to do with your [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) definition. For all intents and purposes, the one supplied simply resolves down to [A1].

Comment: `ActiveCell.Range((Cells(1, 1)), (Cells(1, 1))).Select` simply resolves to `ActiveCell.Select`. In my tests it doesn't go to A1.

Comment: @D_Bester - Good catch! I wasn't thinking that the range as going to be relative to the [ActiveCell property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193314.aspx) but of course it is. Simply the Activecell since he Activecell itself is in position 1.